# How to use filtered range into SUMIF function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a filtered range into SUMIF function. I have some Named Range in my WB ("uselist" in Sheet1 is a column of item and "aliquotes" in Sheet2 is a column of quantity, "dates" in Sheet2 is a column of date `yyyy-mm-dd`).

This formula in my code works as expected (i.e. sum the quantities in "aliquotes" that have the `item=cell.Value` in "uselist" column):

```
Cells(cell.Row, "K") = Application.SumIf(Range("uselist"), cell.Value, Range("aliquotes"))
```

But now I want limit the sum to those rows that have in "dates" column a date between the date reported in Column "O" in Sheet1 and Now. The "cell" I'm working are in Sheet1. I modified the code, but I have some problem:

```
Sub FilterSum()
On Error Resume Next

Dim MyRangeI As Range
Dim MyRangeO As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim XNEWRANGE As Range
Dim wsI As Worksheet
Dim wsO As Worksheet

Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With wsI.UsedRange 'don't consider headers
    Set MyRangeI = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1, 1).Offset(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1))
    MyRangeI.Select
End With

With wsO.UsedRange 'don't consider headers
    Set MyRangeO = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1, 1).Offset(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1))
    MyRangeO.Select
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In MyRangeI.Columns("A").Cells

MyRangeO.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">=" & MyRangeI.Cells(cell.Row, "O"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Now 'Field 9 is tha same of the Named Range "dates"

Set XNEWRANGE = MyRangeO.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

MyRangeI.Cells(cell.Row, "K") = Application.SumIf(XNEWRANGE, MyRangeI.cell.Value, Range("aliquotes"))

Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In my opinion there is a problem with the two different sheets I want use for the macro.

Comment: Try using `XNEWRANGE.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` on your  `Application.SumIf...`

Comment: Sorry, I forget to tell you that the code doesn't work after XNEWRANGE...Field definition

Comment: Yes! you need to use  `Set XNEWRANGE = ...` range objects need the `Set`

Comment: I do it. Same error.

Comment: I'm sorry but you can't edit a question to ask something different. You need to close this one if it's been answered and then open another with the new problem (unless it's from the answer).

Comment: But my question is the same, I don't understand.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem then?

Comment: No, I have a problem, the filter doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

But beware about your `MyRange` because it is not declared on the procedure:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterSum()

    'ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select 'avoid using select

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim XNEWRANGE As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'reference your sheets to avoid using select

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'change MySheet for your working sheet name

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        For Each cell In MyRange.Columns("A") 'MyRange isn't declared or it's value given anywhere
            'Add your filters first
            .Range("dates").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Cells(cell.Row, "O"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Now
            'Set your range using the visible cells from A2 to last row visible on column A
            Set XNEWRANGE = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .Cells(cell.Row, "K") = Application.SumIf(XNEWRANGE, cell.Value, Range("aliquotes"))
        Next cell
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You right, I delete this part of code: `With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Set MyRange = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1, 1).Offset(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1))
        MyRange.Select
    End With`

Comment: I have some troubles, again, could you help me with my new code?