# Autofilter in Sheet2 and use the filtered range for SUMIF in Sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a filtered range into SUMIF function. I have some Named Range in my WB ("uselist" in Sheet1 is a column of item and "aliquotes" in Sheet2 is a column of quantity, "dates" in Sheet2 is a column of date `yyyy-mm-dd`).

This formula in my code works as expected (i.e. sum the quantities in "aliquotes" that have the `item=cell.Value` in "uselist" column):

```
Cells(cell.Row, "K") = Application.SumIf(Range("uselist"), cell.Value, Range("aliquotes"))
```

But now I want limit the sum to those rows that have in "dates" column a date between the date reported in Column "O" in Sheet1 and Now. The "cell" I'm working is in Sheet1. Here my code:

```
Sub FilterSum()
On Error Resume Next

Dim MyRangeI As Range
Dim MyRangeO As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim XNEWRANGE As Range
Dim wsI As Worksheet
Dim wsO As Worksheet

Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With wsI.UsedRange 'don't consider headers
    Set MyRangeI = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1, 1).Offset(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1))
    MyRangeI.Select
End With

With wsO.UsedRange 'don't consider headers
    Set MyRangeO = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1, 1).Offset(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1))
    MyRangeO.Select
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In MyRangeI.Columns("A").Cells 'cell belongs to "uselist" Named Range

MyRangeO.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">=" & MyRangeI.Cells(cell.Row, "O"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Now 'Field 9 is the same of the Named Range "dates"

Set XNEWRANGE = MyRangeO.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

MyRangeI.Cells(cell.Row, "K") = Application.SumIf(XNEWRANGE, MyRangeI.cell.Value, Range("aliquotes"))

MyRangeO.ShowAllData 'reset filter before start new cell
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In my opinion there is a problem with the two different sheets I want use for the macro.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use filtered range into SUMIF function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322892/how-to-use-filtered-range-into-sumif-function)

Comment: You suggested me to open a new question!